# Making an XLL that runs under 32 and 64-bit Excel

Tags: excel-2010, xll

We are using XLDNA to make a small VB.net XLL that loads our data files and places the contents in Excel for editing. When we tried to deploy this among our three-person team, it was like an episode of the Three Stooges - it would work fine on one machine but then tell us that it was not a valid XLL on another, causing much head-smacking.

We realized with was 32/64 related, but also found that the machines in question randomly had the 32 or 64 version of Excel *even though they are all the same model, running the same OS, installing XL from the same DVD*! If we can't figure this out, I suspect our users will have an even harder time of it.

So... is there a way to make a single XLL that contains both 32 and 64 bit code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't make a single XLL for 32 and 64 bit. See the source for an Excel-DNA based project like PMStockQuote. You'll see it generates two distinct .xll binaries, one for x86 and one for x64. I guess you need to fix your install procedure to figure whether EXCEL.EXE lives under c:\Program Files, or c:\Program Files (x86).