# XLW - Compiled XLL "The file format and extension don't match"

Tags: c++, x86, 64-bit, xll, xlw

I'm using `XLW 5` to build an `Excel` `XLL` add in, and am experimenting with the `EchoShort` template example. I successfully compiled `Template.xll` using GNU `Make`, with `g++` version 4.9.2 (mingw-w64) under `cygwin`. However, when trying to open the `XLL`, `Excel 2013` reports the error:

```
The file format and extension of Template.xll don't match. The file could be corrupted, or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Would you like to open it anyway?
```

I proceed to open it, and it seems to be filled with unreadable characters. I tried adding the `xll` using the add-in manager under the developer tab, yet when I try to call `EchoShort` in a cell, I get a `#NAME` error.

I'm new to `XLW` and this seems like an incredible package, if I can get it working. Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: Should have mentioned it's under `cygwin`

EDIT: Also tried with VS2013, and the same thing happened, so it's not `cygwin` nor `MinGW`.

Comment: This deserves at least one upvote I think :) I don't think it's purely xlw related though, you'll get this with any xll where your excel and xll build architecture doesn't match (similar example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154364/making-an-xll-that-runs-under-32-and-64-bit-excel)

Comment: I have same error with Excel.DNA, after office 365 update to x64 it is not working and I dont know why :/ (addin is built to any cpu)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the `VS2013 x64` compiled `xll` works, since I appear to be using Excel 2013 x64. I think I need to clean up my `$PATH`, since `dependency-walker` shows a mixture of `32 bit` and `64 bit` `dll`s?

Comment: If this worked, or you found a different solution, it might be worth posting … assuming you can remember it ;)